# parse.com 1.6 crash analytics not working

Tags: ios, parse-platform, crash-reports

Parse version 1.6
Crash analytics are not working.

I am not able to see the crash logs in dashboard. Configured my app according to this:

https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#crashreporting/iOS

I see the following message when I run the app on simulator:

> Breakpad Uploader: unable to determine minidump file length

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: was your build successful...

Comment: Yes, it was successful

Comment: did u Launch the app without the debugger.

Comment: yes, i did, it crashes but no report in dashboard. Though i see this message in console : Breakpad Uploader: unable to determine minidump file length

Comment: launch the application again from the device and wait for some time as it takes time for first crash report to appear.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you to try using the device for testing the crash report feature, as by design the simulator doesn't work.

"Crash Reporting for iOS only works on a device and not in the simulator." - Björn Kaiser, from Facebook.

Comment: Wow I spent a couple of hours trying to figure out why my stack trace shows "google_breakpadPFC" instead of my actual code. I had uploaded my dSYM and everything. The issue was as you mentioned, running on the actual device fixed it :D - Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

did you initialized crash reporting in app ? ;

```
// Enable Crash Reporting
[ParseCrashReporting enable];

// Setup Parse
[Parse setApplicationId:@"parseAppId" clientKey:@"parseClientKey"];
```

or if you are using Swift

```
// Enable Crash Reporting
ParseCrashReporting.enable();

// Setup Parse
Parse.setApplicationId("parseAppId", clientKey:"parseClientKey")
```

If not please do

You can always follow these step by step [Tutorial](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#analytics/crashreporting/ios/existing) on how to set it up

hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, i did exactly the same. Again, this is the message i see - Breakpad Uploader: unable to determine minidump file length. Do you know what could throw that?

Comment: I think this error is misleading us, since you are in Mac  you can use Breakpad minidump and the corresponding Breakpad
symbol files, then you can run minidump_stackwalk on it and get the
backtrace. check this https://code.google.com/p/google-breakpad/wiki/GettingStartedWithBreakpad

If not then honestly I do  not know.