# Parse.com 1.6 crash analytics upload failure

Tags: ios, parse-platform, crash-reports, google-breakpad

I have a problem getting the new crash reporting in Parse 1.6 to work. The symptoms are the same as [parse.com 1.6 crash analytics not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27477895/parse-com-1-6-crash-analytics-not-working) , but my reputation is too low to add my information.

1) I followed the quick start and guide to set up crash reporting and upload my symbols
https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#crashreporting/iOS
https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#analytics/crashreporting/ios/existing

2) I'm following the instructions to generate a crash report by running the app directly in the simulator (iOS 7-8) and on the device (iOS 6) without a debugger attached. On the simulator I can actually see the minidump being created in Library/Parse/PFCrashReports.

3) When launching the app again I get the message "Breakpad Uploader: unable to determine minidump file length" and the crash dump disappears from the file system. So I assume Parse uses google breakpad under the hood, and the error is created by Uploader.mm because the call to stat() fails. I tried the same call in my own code and it succeeds there.

My gut feeling is that there is either a permission problems, or some other code locks the file while the uploader tries to access it. As the parse libraries are closed source it is hard to check anything, though. It is a bit suspicious that other people don't seem to have a problem with this, which may mean some other settings or configuration problem.