# Parse Crash reporting doesn't work

Tags: ios, parse-platform, crash-reports

I'm trying to setup Parse crash reporting on iOS, using [this guide](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#crashreporting/iOS), but unfortunatly, even after several crashes, there is nothing on my dashboard.

Here is my code (i'm using sdk 1.6.3) :

```
     - (void)crash {
        [NSException raise:NSGenericException format:@"Everything is ok. This is just a test crash."];
     }

     ...

     [ParseCrashReporting enable];
     [Parse setApplicationId:@"********"
          clientKey:@"********"];
     [self performSelector:@selector(crash) withObject:nil afterDelay:10.0];
```

I followed the [troubleshooting guide](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#crashreporting-troubleshooting/iOS):

- Make sure you've enabled Crash Reporting in your App Delegate before you initialize Parse. **DONE**
- If you're testing, make sure Xcode isn't catching the crash with the debugger. **DONE**
- Build, run, stop the app, and then run it from the home screen.
  Crashes are sent on the next run of the app. Make sure the app isn't crashing again before it has a chance to send the crash information. If you're testing, you can ensure this by adding a delay. **DONE**
- Crashes may take up to a minute to show up on the dashboard.**DONE**
- Make sure you don't have any other crash reporting solutions linked to your application, as they might interfere with each other. **DONE, (disable Flurry)**

I tried on both simulator and device, as [recommanded here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27477895/parse-com-1-6-crash-analytics-not-working/27491656#27491656).

Finally, i've this message in my console:

> +[PFAnalytics trackEventually:params:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x10f08ac20

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: It doesnt work for me either- v1.6.3 the same error.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Tried using crash reporting in different apps, won't work.

Comment: I'm having this problem in parse 1.9.0, anyone as well?

Comment: Yes me too, I am having this problem in 1.9.0.

Comment: Still having this problem in 1.9.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse must have a bug in v1.6.3 because I have downloaded v1.6.0 and it works all fine.
You can download it here:

> https://parse.com/downloads/ios/parse-library/1.6.0

And this is the order for enabling:

```
[ParseCrashReporting enable];
[Parse setApplicationId:kParse_AppID clientKey:kParse_ClientKey];
```

Answer (score 1):

This probably doesn't count as any answer but I don't have enough rep to comment.

Have you tried enabling the crash report **AFTER** setting up parse with your keys? I know this was an issue for me when I was trying to enable the local datastore.

I know it goes against the guide but weirder things have happened when I use Parse...

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it doesnt work for me, i have the following exception.     `code`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Crash reporting should be enabled, before you setup Parse.'`code`

Comment: Then it's most likely a glitch in the current version. When I get a chance I'll try to enable crash reports (I'm still using 1.6.0)

Answer (score 1):

Parse 1.7.3 is also busted... upgrade to 1.7.4!! !

EDIT: DONT UPDATE TO 1.7.5 -- that seems to be busted too !!

Comment: it even causes a crash on     [ParseCrashReporting enable];
 which ironically doesn't get reported ;)

Comment: Version 1.7.5 didn't send all crash. Keep crashing. i mean retry.

Answer (score 0):

Latest version Parse SDK 1.6.4 fixes this problem!
https://www.parse.com/docs/downloads