# iOS application crash on [ParseCrashReporting enable]

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, crash

I have updated my application today from parse sdk 1.7.2 tO 1.7.4 and my application start crashing on line where i enable Parse crash reporting in applicationDidFinishLaunching: at `[ParseCrashReporting enable]`

.

here is my crash log

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[Parse _isParseInitialized]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to class 0x109af8f70'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010dffbc65 **exceptionPreprocess + 165  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x000000010d6a2bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x000000010e002fad +[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] +
>   205   3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010df5913c
>   ___forwarding_** + 988    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010df58cd8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120  5   Statwack
>   0x000000010992b144 +[ParseCrashReporting enable] + 52     6   Statwack
>   0x00000001094c5738 -[AppDelegate
>   application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 1816    7   UIKit
>   0x000000010bce9788 -[UIApplication
>   _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 240  8   UIKit                               0x000000010bcea397
>   -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 2540   9   UIKit                               0x000000010bced1de -[UIApplication
>   _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1349   10  UIKit                               0x000000010bcec0d5 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 179
>     11  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010fc5e5e5
>   **31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke_2 + 21   12  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010df2f41c
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 12  13  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010df25165 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341    14  CoreFoundation
>   0x000000010df24923 __CFRunLoopRun + 851   15  CoreFoundation
>   0x000000010df24366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470     16  UIKit
>   0x000000010bcebb42 -[UIApplication _run] + 413    17  UIKit
>   0x000000010bcee900 UIApplicationMain + 1282   18  Statwack
>   0x00000001094c475f main + 111     19  libdyld.dylib
>   0x000000010da1d145 start + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Looks like a very buggy library (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28681248/parse-crash-reporting-doesnt-work)).  Go back to a version that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the ParseCrashReporting.framework to exactly the same version as the ParseSDK often helps. See [Parse CrashReporting Quickstart](https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#analytics/crashreporting/ios/native/existing) or set the same version in the podfile.